# Diff pandas column based on stepdiff

Tags: python, pandas, diff

I want to diff a column but based on the values of another column of my dataframe that indicates the step. For example:

| col | step_diff |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 |
| 13 | 3 |
| 28 | 3 |
| 45 | 3 |
| 45 | 3 |
| 45 | 1 |
| 50 | 1 |

and the output should be:

| col | step_diff | col_dif |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 | NaN |
| 13 | 3 | NaN |
| 28 | 3 | NaN |
| 45 | 3 | 45 |
| 45 | 3 | 32 |
| 45 | 1 | 0 |
| 50 | 1 | 5 |

Comment: are time series data and I am interested in differentiating with step 3 or step 1 depending on the day.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
df['col_diff'] = df['col'] - df.reindex(df.index - df['step_diff'])['col'].to_numpy()
```

Output:

```
   col  step_diff  col_diff
0    0          3       NaN
1   13          3       NaN
2   28          3       NaN
3   45          3      45.0
4   45          3      32.0
5   45          1       0.0
6   50          1       5.0
```

*Details:*

Let's use `reindex` with a difference between the current index and 'step_diff' to create an array of "shifted" 'col' to subtract from current 'col'.

#### Using time series:

```
d = {'col': {Timestamp('2021-01-10 00:00:00', freq='D'): 0,
  Timestamp('2021-01-11 00:00:00', freq='D'): 13,
  Timestamp('2021-01-12 00:00:00', freq='D'): 28,
  Timestamp('2021-01-13 00:00:00', freq='D'): 45,
  Timestamp('2021-01-14 00:00:00', freq='D'): 45,
  Timestamp('2021-01-15 00:00:00', freq='D'): 45,
  Timestamp('2021-01-16 00:00:00', freq='D'): 50},
 'step_diff': {Timestamp('2021-01-10 00:00:00', freq='D'): 3,
  Timestamp('2021-01-11 00:00:00', freq='D'): 3,
  Timestamp('2021-01-12 00:00:00', freq='D'): 3,
  Timestamp('2021-01-13 00:00:00', freq='D'): 3,
  Timestamp('2021-01-14 00:00:00', freq='D'): 3,
  Timestamp('2021-01-15 00:00:00', freq='D'): 1,
  Timestamp('2021-01-16 00:00:00', freq='D'): 1}}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Input df,

```
            col  step_diff
2021-01-10    0          3
2021-01-11   13          3
2021-01-12   28          3
2021-01-13   45          3
2021-01-14   45          3
2021-01-15   45          1
2021-01-16   50          1
```

Calculate col_diff,

```
df["col_diff"] = (
    df["col"]
    - df.reindex(df.index - pd.to_timedelta(df["step_diff"], unit="d"))["col"]
    .to_numpy()
)


df
```

Output:

```
            col  step_diff  col_diff
2021-01-10    0          3       NaN
2021-01-11   13          3       NaN
2021-01-12   28          3       NaN
2021-01-13   45          3      45.0
2021-01-14   45          3      32.0
2021-01-15   45          1       0.0
2021-01-16   50          1       5.0
```

Comment: Great. This one is faster and neat. I was not aware of `.reindex`.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
df['col_diff'] = ([df.col.iloc[pos] - df.col.iloc[pos - step] 
                   if pos - step >=0 else np.nan 
                   for pos, step in enumerate(df.step_diff)])
```

Output

```
>>> df
   col  step_diff  col_diff
0    0          3       NaN
1   13          3       NaN
2   28          3       NaN
3   45          3      45.0
4   45          3      32.0
5   45          1       0.0
6   50          1       5.0
```

Comment: Thanks!! it is useful for me